# Easy and hard are at opposite ends of the scale. What is in the middle?

Tags: single-word-requests

“This is easy.”

“This is ___.” <— what goes there?

“This is hard.”

Comment: I'd say '**Doable**' is quite neutral (or at least, more so than my first thoughts of 'achievable' and 'obtainable')

Comment: **Tedious**. ;-)

Comment: or **Feasible**

Comment: This is of middling difficulty.

Comment: +1 I was looking for the same. Alternatively, consider if you're trying to describe the probability of the person succeeding at the task? If so, there's copious study of [words of estimative probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_of_estimative_probability) (and the case in the middle is often called "even chances" or "about as likely as not").

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but the answers are open to opinion (and reasonable single word answers are unlikely).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderately difficult - would be acceptable but I don't think there is a good single word answer.

Comment: In context, you could easily just say "Moderate." Like, of the salsas, the one of the left is the hottest, the one of the right is the mildest, and the one in the middle is moderate.

Answer (score 2):

A few options here - but there really isn't a middle ground that is as universally understood as easy/hard.

This is possible.

This is straightforward.

This is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [average](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/average)

(Merriam-Webster)

which has a meaning of "being about midway between extremes". Easy and Hard can be considered as extremes.

[Middle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/middle)

(MW)

which has a meaning of "being at neither extreme"

If someone askes me to come up with a word to fit. "It was not extremely difficult nor extremely easy. It was just ________"

I would use average, so-so. or difficult enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is [average](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GURPS).

*Skills are categorized by difficulty: easy, **average**, hard, and very hard (Wikipedia*)

[average](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/average): intermediate between extremes, as on a scale (Houghton-Mifflin's American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language)

Comment: Although you'd always need to additionally specify "average difficulty", since "average" alone can mean any number of things.

Answer (score -1):

There is a word for something that is between easy and hard/difficult. Spells like "intermediate".

Comment: 'Intermediate' is not necessarily related to difficult, while 'easy' and 'hard' are. "Spells like" seems redundant.